# fixing a goofy thing for static int uniform

Tags: java, static

Below is the script that I typed.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomPPHOnG2
{
    public static int uniform(int N)
    {
        return (int) (Math.random() * N);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int M = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(uniform(M));
    }
}
```

But, as I run this program as `java RandomPPHOnG2 100`, I get 100. which is not the number I want.

I want to get a random number from 0 to 100... In particular, how do I adjust `System.out.println(uniform(M));` to print a number between 0 and M?...

Comment: Are you sure this actually produced 100? Even if it actually can (and I'm not sure whether it can), the probability of it doing so would be astronomically unlikely. It's probable that you've reported things incorrectly.

Comment: Also, why did you import `Random` and then not use `Random.nextInt`, the method specifically designed to perform this task?

Comment: Yes. If I put 100, then I get 100. If I put 1354654, then I get 1354654...

Comment: Are you sure your actual code has that `uniform` call in it, rather than just printing `M`?

Comment: @user2357112, I'm looking at a script and try to change something...;; So that is where `Random` came. I guess I didn't used it properly here. But, I actually don't want to use `Random`.

Comment: @user2357112 What do you mean by "are you sure your actual code has that `uniform` call in it, rather than just printing `M`?

Comment: Your error is resulting from code you haven't shown us. The code you've posted does what you want. I am saying that your posted code does not reflect your real code, and asking whether your real code says `System.out.println(uniform(M))` or `System.out.println(M)`.

Comment: "But, I actually don't want to use `Random`". Then write your own random generator. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) related to `random()`: *When this method is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression `new java.util.Random()`
This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.*

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Java has the `Random` class which already offers this functionality with the `nextInt` method.

```
class Main
{
  private final static Random r = new Random();

  public static int uniform(int min, int max)
  {
    // +1 assumes inclusive range, [min,max]        
    return min + r.nextInt(max-min+1); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you also explained why his original code doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain how to adjust my code rather than using your code..?

Comment: That's not my code. That's JDK code. You example compiles and runs fine: http://ideone.com/TJiotr. So the error must be somewhere else, or the code you posted is different from the one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the program as you've written it.

When I compile and run it (using Eclipse and Java 8) with `100` as the command line argument, I get a different number each time.

---

The only faults in the program are stylistic:

- The `import java.util.Random` is redundant because you don't use that class.
- You don't check the size of `args` and hence you can get unexpected exceptions.
- You shouldn't start variable names with uppercase letters; e.g. `M` and `N` should be `m` and `n`.
- The class name conveys no meaning to me ...

Comment: even im getting a different number but as Math#random() returns double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0 then multiplied the value with the input number

Comment: Well... I checeked it at the command prompt, and it worked!.... But, I am keep trying to do it over and over again in the DrJava, and I don't know I keep getting the same problem.. As you said, the script is perfectly fine with the command prompt, but I don't know why there is a problem in DrJava, can you explain this?/

Comment: @Yk26: You're running different code in DrJava. Check which file you're using, save, and recompile.

Comment: Maybe DrJava has a broken implementation of `Math.random()`?  Or maybe you are running different code ... as user2357112 suggests.

Comment: In that case, the problem is that DrJava is broken.  (Maybe it is seeding the random number generator incorrectly.  Try changing the program to print a series of random numbers ...)